# How to divide numbers in 2 rows and find the average to find the grade

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to create an excel file where the grades are calculated automatically.
The teachers will enter the Max marks available for an assignment in the top row,
and individual student marks in each subsequent row.

Now I want to make a formula that can automatically divide the marks obtained by the max marks for each assignment and find the average of all the results.
This would make it so that if a teacher has had 10 assignments, each assignment would automatically be worth 1/10th of the total grade. If the teacher has 5 assignments, each assignment would be worth 1/5th of the total grade. This is the part I am stuck at and I know if I can sort this out the rest of the sheet would be a piece of cake.

I want to make this to make the lives of my teachers easier. I also have no experience with VBscripts but am trying to work it out using standard excel formulae.

So far I have found that if I use the Quotient formula it gives the Value error. If I use a formula that divides every single marks cell by the max marks cell, I get the Div0 error for any empty cells. If I use the SUM of all marks obtained and divide by the SUM of all max marks the answer is wrong (clearly it would be).
aaaand I've run out of ideas!

Please help!
Thanks!

EDIT:
[image: This is the marks and student name area. Note the Max Marks and the marks obtained by different students]

The formula I used to calculate the grades is:

```
=(C10/C8+D10/D8+E10/E8+F10/F8+G10/G8)/COUNT(C8:G8)*30
```

Where row 10 is the marks of the student named 0,
row 8 is the max marks
dividing by the count and multiplying by 30 is taking the average and multiplying by the weight of the classwork.

Comment: Post few sample data and desired output. Then explain logic in brief. Also put formula if you have tried yet.

Comment: I've edited the post above, the formula should give 20.133 in this instance which it does.
But what I need is a formula that can keep doing this regardless of the number of entries. So in this case there are 5, but what if there's 7 or 10? I can't keep changing the formula for that.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: I'm using 2016. Amazing how some curly brackets make it all work properly

Comment: When you press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` then it will automatically add curly beginning and end of formula. It means then formula is entered as array formula. In Office-365 this is automatically work as dynamic array and no need enter ctrl+shift+enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(C10:K10/C8:K8,0))/COUNT(C8:K8)*30
```

If you are on non 365 version of excel then confirm the formula to array entry with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly! Now my teachers will have easy marks recording thanks to your help! Really appreciate it!!

Comment: I tried but i havent got enough rep. Sorry about that

Comment: @Harun24hr soliciting upvotes are not allowed and is of bad taste.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware there is a shortcut for:

```
C10/C8+D10/D8+E10/E8+F10/F8+G10/G8
```

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C10:G10,1/C8:G8)
```

(In other words, you can use `SumProduct()` as `SumDivision()`)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this, Harun24hrs solution worked perfectly. I tried the sumproduct and it didnt work. I was getting an incorrect answer probably because it would not consider each cell divided by the cell above it but rather the sum of a row by the sum of another row.

Comment: @RaheelEssa: I can confirm this is not the case: I have tested this formula and it works fine (it's not performing `Sum(C10:G10)/Sum(C8:G8)`.